# With the Google Voice app, is it possible to send an SMS to multiple people?

Tags: google-voice, sms

I know from the web interface, you can send messages to up to 10 people. However, I haven't figured out how to send an SMS message to multiple people using the Google Voice Android app. Is it possible? If it is, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the current version you can do this easily — just type in another name/number after the first as you would in the web interface.  A comma appears automatically when you click on a suggestion, and all that good stuff.

Comment: This is indeed the case. I was very glad when this feature was finally added.

Answer (score 1):

Like the people who responded said, yes you can, but you will not receive group responses - you get each response as if it was a 1-1 SMS from whoever responds to your original group SMS.

Somewhat defeats the purpose of being able to do this when it can't handle things the other way around.

Also incoming group messages are split the same way, as if it was a 1-1..

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with the stock Google Voice App.  You will have to download an alternative Google Voice SMS app like the aptly named ["Google Voice SMS"](http://www.appbrain.com/app/net.cpedia.gvsms) to send a message to multiple people.  That app costs $2 but there are free apps available.

Comment: This is no longer true. The latest version of GV allows for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can at this time. After each number, type a comma, then the next number, etc. Google Voice gets improved more often than some of the native apps on the phones.